# How to rename multiple columns?

Tags: datatable, dolphindb, identity-column

Suppose a function returns two columns of vectors. I want to aggregate the results of this function into a table and rename each column. I now use `table(t1.event_time as event_time, sr(t,4,4,9) as t4d4, sr(t,10,4,9) as t10d10)`, but it fails to rename the columns and reports an error indicating repetitive column names. Though this issue can be solved by extracting each vector and respectively writing them into the table, I wonder if there is an easier way.

Comment: Can you please show your table structure?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `rename!` function to rename the columns. Though in SQL, `select f(a) as ab` can be used to rename columns, "as" does not work in DolphinDB’s `table` function when it takes functions as parameters.
[image]